# jquery keyup working in all browsers except Firefox

Tags: jquery, cross-browser

I have this code to prevent people entering '£' into a textbox

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery('#cp_price').keypress(function(e){
     if(e.keyCode == 163){
       alert("Exclude the £ sign"); 
       return false;
     }
   });
});
```

It works in all browsers except Firefox. Any reason why this wouldn't work?

Comment: Are you sure the ID (#cp_price) is unique?

Comment: can you elaborate on "doesn't work" ?? My hunch would be that e.keyCode is not working for firefox - maybe try jquery's e.which instead. Also, I would bind the event handler to .keyup instead of .keypress

Comment: ye sorry I mean this code is supposed to stop you entering a pound symbol (£) however in firefox it does nothing and I can enter a £.

@Arjen yep it's definatly unique

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery('#cp_price').keypress(function(e){
     if((e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which) == 163){
       alert("Exclude the £ sign"); 
       return false;
     }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `e.charCode` or `e.which` instead of `keyCode`. The `charCode` value of the event object refers to the printed character. In Firefox 7.0.1, `e.keyCode` equals zero.

You can check the differences in a live demo at: http://asquare.net/javascript/tests/KeyCode.html

Answer (score -1):

try using

```
e.which
```

instead of

```
e.keyCode
```