# highstock chart cancel zoom area selection using "Esc"

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Does any one have any idea about how to cancel zoom area selection after dragging mouse over the chart but not release the mouse yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See connected request [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2422).

And example: http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/72gA7/7/

Snippet:

```
// Generic code to add zoom cancelling by hitting escape
Highcharts.Pointer.prototype.cancelDrag = function () {
    if (this.selectionMarker) {
        this.selectionMarker = this.selectionMarker.destroy();
    }
    this.drop();
};
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.charCode == 27) { // esc
        $.each(Highcharts.charts, function () {
            this.pointer.cancelDrag();
        });
    } // esc
});
```

Comment: Hi Pawel, thanks for you answer. If I just open a webpage in Firefox, if I don't click anywhere of the webpage, the .keyup will be never trigger. But once I click background of the webpage, the .keyup will work. Do you have any idea why is that? Chrome doesn't have this issue.

Comment: Indeed, instead of `keyCode` use `charCode`, see updated answer.

Comment: Hi Pawel, thanks very much for you answer, but I tried to use charCode and it was still not working as expected. For example, in the jsfiddle, I changed keyCode to charCode. You still can not cancel the selection area when opened the page in the first time.

Comment: Then try `e.which`. See similar issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996449/jquery-keyup-working-in-all-browsers-except-firefox).

Comment: I think the above jsfiddle is not working anymore, does this because of a Highcharts update?

Comment: It looks like an issue with iframe - when I click outside the chart, then it works. Have you tried to use that solution in your app? Do you have the same issue? I guess it's something about focus - `keyup` callback is not even fired.